# android softkeyboard pushes layout up

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

So basically i have a main layout which is a log in screen. The problem is that whole Relative-layout goes off the screen when i tap onto Edittext field...

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/skedo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
    android:drawablePadding="13dp"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/email" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
    android:drawablePadding="13dp"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

</EditText>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/button_states" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/forgot_password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imgdesc"
    android:src="@drawable/or" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/register"
    android:background="@drawable/create_account"
     />
```

So when this happens my logo disappears off the screen and i would like it to be showing. The best example would be facebook log in screen, where when you tap on editText it squashes everything and logo is still visible. So how can i achieve such effect?

So when nothing is pressed:
http://postimage.org/image/swdtggnil/

When keyboard appears
http://postimage.org/image/5pbdfrftl/

I want it to behave exactly like that.

Comment: Try change the layout to LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood you can add

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
   android:name="yourActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I tried it worked, but the problem is that user can no longer see log in button, which in my opinion is bad.

Comment: can you link the login button with the enter key of  the keyboard?

Comment: I could, but i want to work exactly like on facebook app. Check first post added screenshots.

Comment: can you try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"?